# How the list.html(Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment-methods/list.html) is works to render and display the payment methods in checkout page

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.2, knockoutjs

I wish to know how the list.html works while displaying the payment methods.

1)How it loops to display the payment methods using below template

**list.html**

```
 <div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
    <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
         class="payment-group">
        <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
             translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
             class="step-title"
             data-role="title">
        </div>
        <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>


    </div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

**list.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (_, ko, utils, Component, paymentMethods, rendererList, layout, checkoutDataResolver, $t, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/payment-methods/list',
            visible: paymentMethods().length > 0,
            configDefaultGroup: {
                name: 'methodGroup',
                component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-group'
            },
            paymentGroupsList: [],
            defaultGroupTitle: $t('Select a new payment method')
        },

        /**
         * Initialize view.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super().initDefaulGroup().initChildren();
            paymentMethods.subscribe(
                    function (changes) {
                        checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod();
                        //remove renderer for "deleted" payment methods
                        _.each(changes, function (change) {
                            if (change.status === 'deleted') {
                                this.removeRenderer(change.value.method);
                            }
                        }, this);
                        //add renderer for "added" payment methods
                        _.each(changes, function (change) {
                            if (change.status === 'added') {
                                this.createRenderer(change.value);
                            }
                        }, this);
                    }, this, 'arrayChange');

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super().
                    observe(['paymentGroupsList']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Creates default group
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initDefaulGroup: function () {
            layout([
                this.configDefaultGroup
            ]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Create renders for child payment methods.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            var self = this;

            _.each(paymentMethods(), function (paymentMethodData) {
                self.createRenderer(paymentMethodData);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @returns
         */
        createComponent: function (payment) {
            var rendererTemplate,
                    rendererComponent,
                    templateData;

            templateData = {
                parentName: this.name,
                name: payment.name
            };
            rendererTemplate = {
                parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
                name: '${ $.$data.name }',
                displayArea: payment.displayArea,
                component: payment.component
            };
            rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
            utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                item: payment.item,
                config: payment.config
            });

            return rendererComponent;
        },

        /**
         * Create renderer.
         *
         * @param {Object} paymentMethodData
         */
        createRenderer: function (paymentMethodData) {
            var isRendererForMethod = false,
                    currentGroup;

            registry.get(this.configDefaultGroup.name, function (defaultGroup) {
                _.each(rendererList(), function (renderer) {

                    if (renderer.hasOwnProperty('typeComparatorCallback') &&
                            typeof renderer.typeComparatorCallback == 'function'
                            ) {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.typeComparatorCallback(renderer.type, paymentMethodData.method);
                    } else {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.type === paymentMethodData.method;
                    }

                    if (isRendererForMethod) {
                        currentGroup = renderer.group ? renderer.group : defaultGroup;

                        this.collectPaymentGroups(currentGroup);

                        layout([
                            this.createComponent(
                                    {
                                        config: renderer.config,
                                        component: renderer.component,
                                        name: renderer.type,
                                        method: paymentMethodData.method,
                                        item: paymentMethodData,
                                        displayArea: currentGroup.displayArea
                                    }
                            )]);
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        },

        /**
         * Collects unique groups of available payment methods
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         */
        collectPaymentGroups: function (group) {
            var groupsList = this.paymentGroupsList(),
                    isGroupExists = _.some(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                        return existsGroup.alias === group.alias;
                    });

            if (!isGroupExists) {
                groupsList.push(group);
                groupsList = _.sortBy(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.sortOrder;
                });
                this.paymentGroupsList(groupsList);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment group title
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getGroupTitle: function (group) {
            var title = group().title;

            if (group().isDefault() && this.paymentGroupsList().length > 1) {
                title = this.defaultGroupTitle;
            }

            return title + ':';
        },

        /**
         * Checks if at least one payment method available
         *
         * @returns {String}
         */
        isPaymentMethodsAvailable: function () {
            return _.some(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                return this.getRegion(group.displayArea)().length;
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Remove view renderer.
         *
         * @param {String} paymentMethodCode
         */
        removeRenderer: function (paymentMethodCode) {
            var items;

            _.each(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                items = this.getRegion(group.displayArea);

                _.find(items(), function (value) {
                    if (value.item.method.indexOf(paymentMethodCode) === 0) {
                        value.disposeSubscriptions();
                        value.destroy();
                    }
                });
            }, this);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below example, It might be help to you

File path :

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName/js/view/payment/list</item> //Call custom Js here
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-payment-methods-list</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.renders</item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.additional-payment-validators</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html

```
<div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-payment-methods-list') --> //Call custom template
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Check this file & change template path

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/list.js
```

template path like this : `'Vendor_ModuleName/payment-methods/list' //Define custom templage path here`

This is just example, you need to create a all files in your custom module.

Comment: the div that  you have mentioned above , How do I get the available payment methods

Comment: Instead of  "payment-methods-list" , I wish to add custom template

Comment: Instead of load default templates for payment methods, I wish to load my custom templates for each payment methods

Comment: So in payment.html  <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customtemplate') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

Comment: Can I do like above what i have commented before or will it break any other functionalities?

Comment: Check my updated answer, it might be help to you.